# Proxmox VE 4.2 issue on OVH servers,LXC can't access internet

Tags: networking, lxc, proxmox, ovh

I have replaced the IP with dummy IPs.

1.2.3.4 is the main IP
5.6.7.194 is the LXC Dedicated IP

Details for main server:

Main IP network interface 1.2.3.4

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        bridge_ports dummy0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up /etc/pve/kvm-networking.sh

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  1.2.3.4
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        gateway  1.2.3.254
        broadcast  1.2.3.255
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        network 1.2.3.0

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address  2607:5300:120:00cc::
        netmask  64
        gateway  2607:5300:120:00FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
        post-up /sbin/ip -f inet6 route add 2607:5300:120:00ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev vmbr0
        post-up /sbin/ip -f inet6 route add default via 2607:5300:120:00ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        pre-down /sbin/ip -f inet6 route del default via 2607:5300:120:00ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        pre-down /sbin/ip -f inet6 route del 2607:5300:120:00ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev vmbr0

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
        address  192.168.100.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.100.0/24' -o vmbr1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.100.0/24' -o vmbr1 -j MASQUERADE
```

LXC container network interface file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 5.6.7.194
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast 5.6.7.194
        gateway 1.2.3.254
        post-up ip  route add 1.2.3.254 dev eth0
        post-up ip route add default via 1.2.3.254
        pre-down ip  route del 1.2.3.254 dev eth0
        pre-down ip  route del default via 1.2.3.254

dns-nameservers 213.186.33.99 # OVH DNS Server
dns-search ovh.net # For faster hosts resolution on the OVH network
```

---

Main IP routing table

```
Main IP Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         1.2.3.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
default         1.2.3.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
1.2.3.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
1.2.3.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr2

LXC container Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         1.2.3.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
1.2.3.254  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

I am not able to resolve the networking issue. Its on OVH servers.Any has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. Everything was right in terms of network configuration. Only the Virtual Mac address was missing so after adding that, The virtual machine starts responding now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your VM is on a different IP network `5.6.7.0/24` than the default gateway `1.2.3.4` that you are trying to use. Of course this could be just a mistake in your question.

However, if they are in different IP networks, you have two options for fixing it:

1) Bridge the public network facing interface with the VM's virtual interface, and assign a public IP to the VM from the main IP subnet, for example `1.2.3.5`. Then you can assign the `1.2.3.254` as the default gateway in the VM. This option requires that you have public IPs available.

2) Make a separate IP network between host and VM. In this case, you do not bridge the public network facing interface with the VM's virtual interface, but you assign a private network IP to the host VM interface, for example `192.168.121.1`.

Then you assign `192.168.121.2` as the IP address in VM, and use `192.168.121.1` as the default gateway.

Finally, you need to add SNAT for the traffic from the private network, so that traffic from the private network is changed to come from the `1.2.3.4` IP. And for any traffic coming from outside to VM, you need to add DNAT for those ports in the host.

Comment: Thanks Tero for your time but i have found a simple solution.